# Can one attend a wedding ceremony where one partner had a non-Orthodox conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, orthodox, intermarriage

I am unfamiliar with the nuances of what occurs in a non-Orthodox conversion. However, I have heard from a few Orthodox rabbis and friends that a non-Orthodox conversion is "invalid" and the convert is not actually Jewish.

I see that [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12713/5275) addresses whether a Jew can attend an intermarriage ceremony. Is there any leniency regarding attending one where a Jew marries a convert from a non-Orthodox wedding? Or does this have the same rules as if this were an intermarriage?

Comment: Non-Orthodox conversions oftentimes do not have proper three men serving as the Beis Din. This is usually the problem with Conservative conversions. Additional problems include not proper kabbalas mitzvos, not proper mikvah and bris milah, etc. Although there are rare cases in which someone who converted non-Orthodox end up having a kosher conversion, this is very rare and we automatically assume the conversion was not kosher and the person is still not Jewish. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @ezra What's etc.? You literally listed every possible problem. And how often is something really wrong with the mikvah or milah?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Possibly a lot. I am no expert in the field of mikvaos and milah, but for one thing, I don't think Reform Judaism does the mikvah in the conversion process, and also maybe the tools used to draw blood/do the bris itself aren't good ways of doing it. All Orthodox mohelim I know of use a knife and such for milah but Reform and Conservative rabbis will use a different tool. Like I said, I am no expert in this field but maybe that could be a problem.

Comment: If a conversion is invalid, then the person is not Jewish at all. Given that, how can there be a leniency?