# Conservative converts wanting to marry Orthodox

Tags: marriage, conversion-to-judaism, orthodox, conservative-judaism

If there were an instance where a Conservative convert woman wanted to marry an Orthodox man, would an Orthodox rabbi perform the ceremony?

Comment: The answers to this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/is-there-any-benefit-for-a-gentile-to-convert-through-one-denomination-versus-an/26729#26729

Comment: And the comments to this question should give you the information you're looking for: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86454/can-one-attend-a-wedding-ceremony-where-one-partner-had-a-non-orthodox-conversio

Comment: Short answer -- unless she upgrades the conversion to Orthodox, no.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question is likely to be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any benefit for a gentile to convert through one denomination versus another?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/is-there-any-benefit-for-a-gentile-to-convert-through-one-denomination-versus-an)